# How to deserilize nested array json with only value using Gson?

Tags: arrays, json, nested, gson

The input json is:

```
{
    "players":
    [
        [
            [
              "192.168.1.0",
              "8888"
            ],
            "id_1"
        ],            
        [
            [
              "192.168.1.1",
              "9999"
            ],
            "id_2"
        ]
    ],
    "result":"ok"
}
```

I got this message from a server. The server tells me the result and player list. Each player has a unique id, and several contact address, which perhaps is more that one (ip+port). The difficult part for me is the item in the array only has value. It's not like string:value.

Could anyone tell me how to deserialize it with gson?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Agree. Complaints have been made. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in `players` is a `Map` represented as JSON arrays.

It's an *ugly* map, but it's still a `Map`. The key is `List<String>` (IP and Port) with the value being a `String` (the "id")

It's almost like whomever wrote the server made a mistake and did it backwards especially given your description of what this is *supposed* to be. It really should look like:

> ["id_1",[["192.168.1.0","8888"], [another ip/port], ... ]

for each entry. That would make more sense, with the (`String`) "id" being the key and `List<List<String>>` as the value.

That's still ugly as they really should be using object to represent IP/Port. Ideally you would want:

> ["id_1",[{"ip":"192.168.1.1", "port":"8888"},{ "ip":"192.168.1.2","port":"8889"}]]

Below demonstrates how it's currently written:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String json = "{\"players\":[[[\"192.168.1.0\",\"8888\"],\"id_1\"],[[\"192.168.1.1\",\"9999\"],\"id_2\"]],\"result\":\"ok\"}";


    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    MyClass c = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
    c.listPlayers();

}

class MyClass 
{
    public String result;
    public Map<List<String>, String> players;

    public void listPlayers()
    {
        for (Map.Entry<List<String>, String> e : players.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(e.getValue());
            for (String s : e.getKey())
            {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> id_1
>   192.168.1.0
>   8888
>
> id_2
>   192.168.1.1
>   9999

You can get a bit creative and make the key to the map a little more usable with:

```
class IpAndPort extends ArrayList<String> {

    public String getIp() {
        return this.get(0);
    }

    public String getPort() {
        return this.get(1);
    }

}
```

then change:

```
public Map<List<String>, String> players;
```

to:

```
public Map<IpAndPort, String> players;
```

in `MyClass`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I agree it's poor design. I guess the idea is to keep consistent with the error message as below: {"message": "Missing port", "result": "error"}. I have another question. When the client receive a response from the server, it's not able to determine the request if it's fail unless it parse the json response. But how does it parse the successful one above and failed one at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: how does it parse the successful one above and failed one at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: @zhangwei - So, what you would need to do is add a `message` field to your POJO (`MyClass` in the example above) and always check the `result` first to see if it is an error or contains data. GSON will set any missing fields to `null` when it parses the JSON.